# How to prevent duplicate records insert into shopping cart (PHP)

Tags: php

I am currently working on a shopping cart.
I would like to prevent the it from having duplicate items on the shopping cart.
For example:
If I click on "panda", the qty in shopping cart will be 1.
If I click on "panda" again, the qty will change to 2 , instead of having 2 "panda" items in the shopping cart.
Can someone please guide me?
I'm new to PHP, your help will be appreciated.
Thank you

Here are my code.

details.php

```
   if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {

$status = $this->checkProductStatus($yourdata)
if ($status){
// write your update query
$updateSQL = sprintf("UPDATE supermarketcart SET qty=%s WHERE id=%s",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['description'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['package'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['price'], "double"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['imagename'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"));

}
else{
//write your insert query

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO supermarketcart (pname, pdescription, package, pprice, pimage, username) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['name'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['description'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['package'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['price'], "double"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['imagename'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['username'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "cart.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}

$colname_supermarketDetails = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['desc_sel'])) {
  $colname_supermarketDetails = $_GET['desc_sel'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
$query_supermarketDetails = sprintf("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE `description` = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_supermarketDetails, "text"));
$supermarketDetails = mysql_query($query_supermarketDetails, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_supermarketDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc($supermarketDetails);
$totalRows_supermarketDetails = mysql_num_rows($supermarketDetails);

mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
$query_cart = "SELECT * FROM supermarketcart";
$cart = mysql_query($query_cart, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_cart = mysql_fetch_assoc($cart);
$totalRows_cart = mysql_num_rows($cart);

$colname_supermarketInfo = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
  $colname_supermarketInfo = $_GET['id'];




}
mysql_select_db($database_MyDatabase, $MyDatabase);
$query_supermarketInfo = sprintf("SELECT * FROM supermarket WHERE `description` = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_supermarketInfo, "text"));
$supermarketInfo = mysql_query($query_supermarketInfo, $MyDatabase) or die(mysql_error());
$row_supermarketInfo = mysql_fetch_assoc($supermarketInfo);
}

public function checkProductStatus($data){
// check the if the product already exist against that user
return true 
else false
}
```

Comment: Why are you still using the `mysql_*` methods? They're deprecated, crap and have been superseded by PDO and MySQLi

Comment: before the insert query check if the item already exist in cart then make update query of the QTY else insert query.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")){
$status = $this->checkProductStatus($yourdata)
if ($status){
// write your update query
}
else{
//write your insert query
}
}

public function checkProductStatus($data){
// check the if the product already exist against that user
return true else false
}
```

Comment: i just gave u a hint..!! write your query in checkProductStatus function by checking the product with database.!! You must be having a unique product key or some thing so use that to check against database and return true or false according to that.!